# SelectLayerByAttribute in ArcPy creating copy of layer

Tags: arcpy, data-management

I'm trying to use the SelectByAttribute_management tool in ArcPy using :

```
import arcpy

arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("Name_Layer",'NEW_SELECTION')
```

When I write it in the console, the selection is created on a copy of the layer that is added to my map. When I tried it in a script, nothing is happening (no selection is made).

What would cause that and how could I fix it?

Comment: `selection = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("Name_Layer",'NEW_SELECTION').getOutput(0)`

Comment: Are you using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro or with ArcMap?

Comment: I'm guessing nothing is happening because you didn't set anything for the `where_clause` parameter.  It might look like `arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('Name_Layer', 'NEW_SELECTION', "my_text_field = 'value' OR my_short_field = 1")`

Comment: Also if you don't want a view layer to be created, you could do `arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False` before doing the selection, and/or as user2856 said write the output to a variable that you use instead of the original feature class name later on in your script.

Comment: The syntax you are using indicates ArcMap.  In ArcGIS Desktop/ArcMap, you must pass a layer or table view to the tool.  When you are using the console, `Name_Layer` seems to exist in the table of contents of the dataframe since the code works.  When running as a script, are you using [Make Feature Layer (Data Management)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) first to create the layer?